# Comparing a dictionary and a list of dictionaries Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, compare

I'm new to Python.

I'm trying to compare a dictionary **results** against a list of dictionaries **d**. If it's equal to a dictionary in the list **d** (apart from lacking in results 'name' key), I should print one of the values (name), if not equal to any - print no match.

In particular:
**d** - list of dictionaries:

```
[OrderedDict([('name', 'Alice'), ('AAA', '2'), ('BBB', '8'), ('CCC', '3')]), OrderedDict([('name', 'Bob'), ('AAA', '4'), ('BBB', '1'), ('CCC', '5')]), 
OrderedDict([('name', 'Charlie'), ('AAA', '3'), ('BBB', '2'), ('CCC', '5')])]
```

**results** - dictionary:

```
{'AAA': 4, 'BBB': 1, 'CCC': 5}
```

Since *results* is identical to the similar part of the dict list *d*, I should return 'name' in that d dict list (Bob in this case)

I was trying the following code, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
for i in range(len(d)):
    if key in d[i] != 'name':
        for k, v in results.items and d[i].items():
            if results.items() == d[i].items():
                print(d[i]['name'])
else:
    print("No match")
```

I'd be happy if you could provide some simple and more detailed explanations, as I'm not advanced yet:)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a one-liner:

```
next((x["name"] for x in d
      if results == {k: int(v) for k, v in x.items() if k != 'name'}),
     "No match")
# Output: 'Bob'
```

---

Alright, so that's not super helpful. Let's debug your code.

```
for k, v in results.items and d[i].items():
    if results.items() == d[i].items():
```

The problem in your code is that you are comparing a list of key-value pair *as a sequence*. There's no guarantee that the regular dict (non-OrderedDict) will give you the `.items()` in the same order as the OrderedDict. Instead you could just say (with a little bit of dict-comprehension:

```
if {k: int(v) for k, v in d[i].items() if k != 'name'} == result:
    print(d[i]["name"])
```

PS: Please use the slightly better: `for item in items: something(item)` instead of `for i in range(len(items)): something(items[i])` construct. Put this together with a little bit list/dict comprehension you'll get the answer in the first line. :)

Comment: thanks a lot, that's very helpful! A couple of clarifying questions: 1) why do you use int(v) in the first piece of code and without int in the second? 2) I was trying to incorporate for now the second piece of code in my previous code, making it `for i in range(len(d)):
    if results == {k: int(v) for k, v in d[i] if k != 'name'}:
        print(d[i]['name'])
    else:
        print("No match")` but it returns error ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2) - why could that be? Thanks!

Comment: 1) I should have used `int(..)` in both. That's because your `d` variable has values as strings, and your `result` variable has values as integer. You need to convert either one to the other. 2) This was written without actually testing. That's why you see the two problems you pointed out. It should be `d[i].items()`.

Comment: Fixed. I don't have access to a Python interpreter now, hopefully it should work :)

Answer (score 1):

Easy to understand:

```
done = False
for di in d:
    l = list(di.values())
    l.pop(0)
    l = [int(i) for i in l]
    if l == list(results.values()):
        print(di['name'])
        done = True
if done == False:
    print('no match found')
```

Output for your results dictionary:

```
Bob
```